# From an array of ids to an array of names (mongo, nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async.js

I've been poking around this for several hours... Thanks for any help.

I have a "Users" collection, each user has an `_id` and some names (`Username`, `FirstName`, `LastName`).
I also have a "Group" collection, each group has `Members`, which is an array of users' `_id`.

At first I wanted a simple function that receives an array of ids and turns it into an array of strings in a nice format: `FirstName + " " + LastName + " (" + Username + ")"`. So I made a simple `for` for that:

```
    var ans = [];
    for (i=0; i<arrOfIds.length; i++) {
        users.find({"_id": ObjectID(arrOfIds[i])}, function(err, result){
            ans.push = result.FirstName + result.LastName + "(" + result.Username + ")";
        });
    }
```

But since mongo is async that didn't work. After some reading, I installed [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) which I thought will solve my problem. I tried just async, [async.whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst), [async.times](https://github.com/caolan/async#times) and even tried to hack something with [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) - but nothing worked - pretty much all ended the same way: the array was passed before the strings were push to it.

Maybe my approach to this task is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have an array of user ids then it would be best if you convert that string array to an array of ObjectIds using the **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method and then in the [**`find()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find) query use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator which selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

You would need to call the **[`toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray)** method on the **[`find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find)** cursor so that you can get the results in an array, further manipulate the array to return the desired result, something like the following:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    // Get users collection
    var Users = db.collection('users');

    // Retrieve all the documents in the collection
    Users.find({ "_id": { "$in": arrOfIds.map(ObjectID) } })
         .toArray().then(function(users) {
             // Create array of names
             var ans = users.map(function (u){
                 return u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName + " (" + u.Username + ")";       
             });

             // Do something with the result
             console.log(ans);
             db.close();
         });  
});
```

---

Another approach is taking the aggregate route in which you can use the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step to create the desired array with **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)** and **[`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/)** operators.

Consider running the following aggregate operation:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    // Get users collection
    var Users = db.collection('users');

    // Retrieve all the documents in the collection
    Users.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": arrOfIds.map(ObjectID) } } },
        { "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "users": { 
                "$push": {
                    "$concat": ["$FirstName", " ", "$LastName", " (", "$Username", ")"]
                }
            }
        } }
    ]).toArray().then(results => {

        const ans = results[0].users;

        // Do something with the result
        console.log(ans);
        db.close();
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`$in` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) to find multiple users with a single query. This is both better for performance and less hassle with asynchronicity.

```
// Convert the list of ids to mongo object ids
var objectIds = arrOfIds.map(function(item) {
  return ObjectId(item);
});

// Use the $in operator to find multiple users by id
users.find({ "_id": { $in: objectIds } }, function(err, result) {
  // result is now a list of users
});
```